Langchain generate_query Error with Gemini
I know this might be model specific but OpenAI API correctly outputs the the syntax of
print(query)
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CNS_SEX_AGE_RACE;'

Gemini API
print(query)
'```sql\nSELECT COUNT(*) AS "row_count"\nFROM CNS_SEX_AGE_RACE;\n```'

which in turn fails the query structure
from langchain_community.tools.sql_database.tool import QuerySQLDataBaseTool
execute_query = QuerySQLDataBaseTool(db=db)
execute_query.invoke(query)

How can I fix this query to actually only produce the sql statement without the ''' quotes easily?
